# Dataframe don`t return full results Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
with open('btc_bars2.csv', newline='\n') as d:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(d)
    bars = list(csv_reader)

    print(bars)
    
    
    btc_df = pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
    btc_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    print(btc_df.head())
```

I have csv file with 1000 rows when I load it and transfer it to a list when I pass it to dataframe it returns only 5 row that many are the columns I can't find why this happens.

Comment: Double check the docs for [`pandas.DataFrame.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).

Answer (score 0):

`df.head()` gives you the first five rows, if you want all rows then `print(df)`.

Comment: I must know this.Thank you.